# Provide an example to create class without getter and setter

Tags: oop, class, encapsulation

I need an example to understand more clearly, How can I create a class with out getter and setter. So to implement a better design and adapt below mentioned principle:

- Keeping code more object oriented and avoid procedural style coding
- Reduce Law Of Demeter
- Do not violate DRY principle
- How to keep details of a class hidden from other classes
- So that the calling class (client class) will not be created containing procedural methods which will make decision based on the state of my class.

Comment: can you tell me why you want to avoid getter and setter ?

Comment: So that the calling class (client class) will not be created containing procedural methods which will make decision based on the state of my class.

Answer (score 0):

I think Knowledge of access modifiers will help you to answer own questions. Please check.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25078/C-Access-Modifiers-Quick-Reference